# View files that I have committed locally in Git and Mercurial

Tags: git, mercurial

Once I have locally commited my code, doing either `hg status` or `git status` will *not* show me the files I have already committed (but not pushed).

How can I view the files that are ready to be pushed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Mercurial you simply do :

```
hg outgoing
```

Or you can do `hg out` which is the shorthand of the `outgoing` command.

`outgoing` take some arguments to refine the output or show additionnal information, you can see the help by doing `hg help outgoing`.

For example, if you want to see the diff with the remote repository, add the `patch` option :

```
 hg out -p
```

Comment: great, how could I compare an outgoing file with what's in the main remote repository (master)?

Comment: The `hg help outgoing` mentioned in my answer tells you the following : `-p --patch show patch` ... So you can just do `hg out -p`

Answer (score 1):

in git you would

```
git diff ..origin/master --stat
```

if you were working on master and origin is what you named your remote. Haven't used Hg.

In DVCS (distributed version control system), there is the idea of pushing the commits that you did locally to a remote repository. This is an explicit step and is done at the commit level. It's up to you if you want to do this right after each commit or do it in batches. "status" will only show you changes you have not committed. It does not care about previous commits.

In git, if you have set your current branch to track a remote one, you will have a "ahead of remote by X commits" telling you how many commits will be pushed when you decide to do so.